# Component is not being returned in nested loop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the child component inside a nested loop. However it is not being render in the second loop(red tick). Although it is rendered normally in the first loop (blue tick). Kindly highlight why is it no rendered in the second loop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFiKU.png

Codesandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-nova-u9rzuh?file=/src/parent.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ProductFeaturesCards from "./ProductFeaturesCards.js";
import { Products } from "../ProductsData.js";

const ProductFeatures = ({ className = "", id }) => {
  return (
    <section id='product-features' className={`${className}`}>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row d-flex justify-content-center'>
          <div className='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 py70'>
            <p className='features-title'>Product Features</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          {Products.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (item.id === id) {
              // return <ProductFeaturesCards data={item} key={i} />;
              Object.values(item.Product_features[0]).map((feature, index) => {
                console.log("ProductFeaturesCards:", feature);
                return <ProductFeaturesCards data={feature} key={index} />;
              });
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ProductFeatures;
```

Comment: could you please add it to sandbox or add more detail ?to see what's happening

Comment: You're returning from the callback, and not the parent render function.

Comment: @DeanJames how to solve this issue?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I have tried to replicate the issue in the codesandbox; link given in the edited version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. Not sure if this will work

```
 if (item.id === id) {
      // return <ProductFeaturesCards data={item} key={i} />;
      return Object.values(item.Product_features[0]).map((feature, index) => {
           console.log("ProductFeaturesCards:", feature);
           return <ProductFeaturesCards data={feature} key={index} />;
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake you did was using forEach. forEach will mutate the data and will not return anything. So, Instead you need to use map which doesn't mutate and returns the result.

The 2nd mistake is the return statement not added inside the if condition for the map. So, it never gets returned and hence your first map will not receive the value.

After this you should be able to run it.

```
<div className="row">
          {Products.map((item) => { // replaced forEach with map
           if (item.id === id) {
            return Object.values(item.Product_features[0]).map( // return added
                (feature, index) => {
                  return <Card data={feature} key={index} />;
                }
            );
           }
          })}
</div>
```